# How to get all elements even if they have the same data

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, hashmap, mapping

I have a project where I would like to gather in all **brandname** and **price** from a site.
for that reason I have the following code:

```
List<WebElement> list_of_products = driver.findElements(By.xpath(loc.getProperty("brandName")));
    List<WebElement> list_of_products_price = driver.findElements(By.xpath(loc.getProperty("finalPrice")));


    //System.out.println("ezek a termékek"+ list_of_products);
    // Use of HashMaop to store Products and Their prices(after conversion to
    // Integer)
    String product_name;
    String product_price;
    int int_product_price;
    HashMap<Integer, String> map_final_products = new HashMap<>();
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < list_of_products.size(); i++) {

            product_name = list_of_products.get(i).getText();// Iterate and fetch product name
            product_price = list_of_products_price.get(i).getText();// Iterate and fetch product price
            product_price = product_price.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");// Replace anything will space other than numbers
            int_product_price = Integer.parseInt(product_price);// Convert to Integer
            map_final_products.put(int_product_price, product_name);// Add product and price in HashMap
        }

        // write out all the products we found
         Reporter.log("All the prices and products we found: " +
         map_final_products.toString()+ "\n", true);

        // Get all the keys from Hash Map
        Set<Integer> allkeys = map_final_products.keySet();
        ArrayList<Integer> array_list_values_product_prices = new ArrayList<Integer>(allkeys);

        // this will sort in ascending order lowest at the top and highest at the bottom
        Collections.sort(array_list_values_product_prices);
```

As it is on console:
*XYs are the actual brandnames*

> All the prices and products we found: {20720=XY,
> 11490=XY, 13490=XY, 15490=XY,
> 19490=XY, 21990=XY, 16490=XY, 18490=XY
> 20490=XY, 18990=XY, 20990=XY}

As I think my **code just does not write out** or collect **when the price is the same** with other brands(or with the same brands too). For example:
At the website there are more products for 13490.. and lots of for 18490.

How can I modify my code in order to get all the pairs even if they have same prices?

Comment: Since you are adding items to a HashMap where int_product_price is your key, the implementation overwrites the value for that entry if you happen to have similar keys. Instead of writing the elements to a map, you might want to use a list instead.

Answer (score 0):

@Peter Santa, you should have product Name as your key instead of Price. So you can reverse the location. But this will not print the same product with the same or different price. Which I feel should be ok assuming, the same product will not have different prices on the same website.